# Substitution from historical shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command like this in my history (Linux bash shell):

```
1119 for dir in `ls -d MyMod.*`; \
    do echo $dir;  \
svn copy --parents $dir $REPO/tags/MyMod_20101115/$dir -m"MyMod tag for 20101115"; \
done
```

where 1119 is the command number.

*(Note that the command is in reality all on one line and does not contain any \ characters. I just put those in to let it fit on the page here)*

Is there a one-liner you can use to modify the above from 20101115 to 20101118 (representing a tag of today's date). Obviously we could create a script to do this.

This is not a question about SVN. The example above is an SVN example but the purpose of the question is to know how to do the substitution, particularly given that it is in the history and uses a for. We have tried using echo !1119 mixed with sed and are not getting the desired result.

Comment: I think you are looking how to extract certain line from the ~/.bash_history?

Comment: Modify the line in history with substitution and execute it. Executing it can be done with xargs although I would need to strip off the command number. Effectively I am trying to do ^$OLDDATE^$NEWDATE but not for the most recent command. Surprised this is more difficult than I had imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!1119:gs/20101115/20101118`

See 'History Expansion' in your bash manual

Comment: I tested this out on a slightly different example (just listing the directory the changing the search path - as I didn't want to create a new SVN tag anymore) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`tail +1119 ~/.bash_history | head -1 | sed -e "s/20101115/20101118/g"`

or

`history | tail +1119 | head -1 | awk -F"  "  '{print $3 $4}' | sed -e "s/$OLD/$NEW/g"`

Comment: ~/.bash_history is not updated while in a bash session. I suggest `history | awk 'NR=1119' | sed...`

Comment: These do not work: the latter one is just outputting all of history with the substitution. Even if I reduce it by grep, I always get the most recent command, i.e. the one I am just calling, and I still get the prefix (1119) so can't xargs it.

Answer (score 1):

```
fc -s 20101115=20101118 1119
```

Comment: I have tested this solution and it works too. I don't think I can have 2 accepted answers, but I have given you a +1.